# Scala Routing Error

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I am new to Scala and Play.
I have called the function from Application.scala in the html page as follows

```
<form action="@routes.Application.register()" class="pull-center">
        <div class="content">
            First Name:<input type="text" id="First Name"/>
            Last Name: <input type="text" id="Last Name"/>
            User Name: <input type="text" id="UserName"/>
            Password:  <input type="text" id="Password"/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
        </div>
 </form>
```

However, I am getting the error message as follows:

```
value register is not a member of controllers.ReverseApplication
```

I have specified the route as follows in the routes file as follows:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                                controllers.Application.index
GET     /room                            controllers.Application.chatRoom(username: Option[String])
GET     /room/register          controllers.Application.register
GET     /room/chat                       controllers.Application.chat(username)
GET     /assets/javascripts/chatroom.js  controllers.Application.chatRoomJs(username: String)

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file                    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

In the Application.scala the function can be defined as follows:

```
def register() = Action { register =>
    Ok(views.html.register())

  }
```

How are the static URI's created  ? Also what is going wrong in my application which is causing this error ?

Answer (score 0):

you can give hard coded static url

```
<form action="/room/register" class="pull-center">
```

but when i tried your code i also get the same error at eclipse, so i clean my project and bingo error removed from eclipse.
 you can ignore the eclipse errors, your code works fine.